# Loopback Angular SDK Login Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, loopbackjs, angular-loopback

I created a "user" named model with base class "User". I'm trying to login a user in Angular App using `lb-ng` generated service but it's not logging in.
In my Login controller I invoked `User.login()` providing email and password but its giving some weird error.

Even I included this code in my app.js

```
// Use a custom auth header instead of the default 'Authorization'
LoopBackResourceProvider.setAuthHeader('X-Access-Token');

// Change the URL where to access the LoopBack REST API server
LoopBackResourceProvider.setUrlBase('http://.../api');
```

In loginController

```
console.log(User.login({ email: "shah.khokhar@hotmail.com", password: "12345" }));
```

But it's giving this validation error:

[image]

Kindly help me on this.
Thanks,

Comment: Why are you calling User.login()? Shouldn't it be user.login()? Also, can you post your json file?

Answer (score 0):

If you could post your `user.json` file and your actual angular code then it would be more clear. But as far as I can see, there are things you are doing wrong.

1. You are making a request to `User` model instead of your custom `user` model which obviously won't work as your user data is present in your custom model and not the built in `User` model
2. You are most probably making a POST request to a wrong method than login method as login method request url looks something like this
   `http://localhost:3000/api/users/login`

Here's a working sample code for login function which I use for my project

```
self.login = function () {
            var data = {
                email: self.email,
                password: self.password
            };
            users.login(data).$promise
                .then(function (user) {
                    $state.go('home');
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    $state.go('auth.register');
                });
        };
```

Hope this helps.